# How can I get SharedPreferences of a PreferenceActivity from another class in android?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm new at android. I have a little idea over sharedPreference. Some tutorials say to add preferences in a xml file, but I need to add preferences dynamically. So I done that from a java class(my settings page).

```
PreferenceScreen root = getPreferenceManager().createPreferenceScreen(this);
CheckBoxPreference checkboxPref = new CheckBoxPreference(this);
        checkboxPref.setKey("1");
        checkboxPref.setTitle("SomeRandomStuff");
        root.addPreference(checkboxPref);
```

Now,  Now I need to get title of all selected checkbox (true) from that settings page to show which option been selected.

How can I do that? 
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a regular checkbox and sharedPreferences. Just add it's state like this

```
 // global variables
SharedPreferences data;
public static String filename = "prefs";

// setup the SharedPreferences in onCreate()
data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);

// set the SharedPreference based on checkbox state
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
    switch (arg0) {
    case R.id.checkBox1:
        boolean checked = checkBox1.isChecked();
        SharedPreferences.Editor e = dataAddHS.edit();
        e.putBoolean("preferenceName", checked);
        e.commit();
    break;
    }
```

then when you need to pull the preference state, just do

```
boolean checked = data.getBoolean("preferenceName", false);
```

then you can use an if statement to see if checked is true or false, etc.

Comment: haven't saved preferences in any file. Just declared in a class (which extends PreferenceActivity). Should I save them in any file ?

Answer (score 0):

From what you're saying, it sounds like all you need is a default value for the preferences you will be working with.  To be specific, you may have a bunch of checkbox-preferences that you want to use.  When you read them, you can use the [getBoolean](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getBoolean%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29) method to get their values.

Note that the getBoolean method takes a second argument, which is the default value to return.

This means that you don't have to set the preferences dynamically.  You use getBoolean to read the preferences and if the preferences have not been set by the user, a default value that you specify will be returned.

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
sp.getBoolean("whether_user_wants_setting1", false);
```